# How to use a Boolean variable when reading through user input

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, boolean, user-input

In my code, I am creating a window where a user can input a phrase. I am then setting up a for loop to read through the input and add `ub` before any vowel. My problem now is that if the user input is `aeiou` the output I want is `ubaeiou` and not `ubaubeubiuboubu`. I believe a Boolean variable would help but I am stuck on how to do this portion.

```
public void buttonPressed() {

    String line = input1.getText(); 
    String finline;
    finline = "";
    line = line.toLowerCase();

    for(int i =0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if((line.charAt(i) == 'a') || (line.charAt(i) == 'e') || (line.charAt(i)     == 'i') || (line.charAt(i) == 'o') || (line.charAt(i) == 'u')) 
         {
          finline = finline + "ub" + line.charAt(i);
         }

        else 
         {
          finline = finline + line.charAt(i);
         }
    }
    output.setText(finline);
}
```

> User input = aeiou
>
> Output = ubaubeubiuboubu
>
> Desired output = ubaeiou

Comment: I think you need to show some more examples of what you want. If you had "aba," would that expand to "ubaba" or "ubabuba"?

Answer (score 0):

You want the "ub" prefix on the first vowel of the LINE?  Then use a boolean to trigger an early loop exit.

```
public void buttonPressed() {

    Boolean done = false;
    String line = input1.getText(); 
    String finline;
    finline = "";
    line = line.toLowerCase();

    for(int i =0; i < line.length() && !done; i++) {
        if((line.charAt(i) == 'a') || (line.charAt(i) == 'e') || (line.charAt(i)     == 'i') || (line.charAt(i) == 'o') || (line.charAt(i) == 'u')) 
         {
          finline = finline + "ub" + line.charAt(i);
          done = true;
         }

        else 
         {
          finline = finline + line.charAt(i);
         }
    }
    output.setText(finline);
}
```

Or if you want it on the first vowel of EACH WORD, you'll need to work the boolean into the vowel check condition and make sure it gets turned off on word breaks.

```
public void buttonPressed() {

    Boolean checkVowel = true;
    String line = input1.getText(); 
    String finline;
    finline = "";
    line = line.toLowerCase();

    for(int i =0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if(checkVowel && ((line.charAt(i) == 'a') || (line.charAt(i) == 'e') || (line.charAt(i) == 'i') || (line.charAt(i) == 'o') || (line.charAt(i) == 'u'))) 
         {
          finline = finline + "ub" + line.charAt(i);
          checkVowel = false;
         }

        else 
         {
          finline = finline + line.charAt(i);
          if (line.charAt(i) == ' ') checkVowel = true;
         }
    }
    output.setText(finline);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String line = "aeiou";
    String finline;
    finline = "";
    line = line.toLowerCase();
    Boolean flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        Boolean flagLine = (line.charAt(i) == 'a') || (line.charAt(i) == 'e') || (line.charAt(i) == 'i') || (line.charAt(i) == 'o')
                || (line.charAt(i) == 'u');
        if (flag && flagLine) {
            finline = finline + "ub" + String.valueOf(line.charAt(i));
            flag = false;
        }

        else {
            if(!flagLine) flag = true;
            finline = finline + String.valueOf(line.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(finline);
```

input = aeiou
output = ubaeiou

input = aeqou
output = ubaequbou